# Concurrent/Parallel Http calls in a Queue with throttle

Tags: f#, queue, message-queue

If you have lots of URLs to call get on, are there any queue patterns in F# with some kind of limit, like let's say 5 or 10 calls at a time before proceeding to the next batch.

```
let urls = [
    "http://example.com/1", 
    "http://example.com/2", 
    "http://example.com/3",
    ....
    "http://example.com/100"]
```

While passing a function to call

```
let getAsync (url:string) = 
    async {
        let httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient()
        let! response = httpClient.GetAsync(url) |> Async.AwaitTask
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode () |> ignore
        let! content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
        return content
}
```

and then receive a list of all **results** and any **errors** since some calls may fail due to any reason like 404 or 500 errors.

Comment: what's wrong with the question?

Comment: Technically, it's not a question? For a bit of google foo, you may find [http://www.fssnip.net/oz/title/Throttling-agent](http://www.fssnip.net/oz/title/Throttling-agent).

Comment: awesome, thanks for the link,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make your function actually *return* the error information instead of throwing it as an exception:

```
let getAsync url : Result<_,_> =
    async {
        try
            ...
            return (Ok content)
        with ex ->
            return (Error ex)
    }
```

Then use [`Async.Parallel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/async.parallel%5B't%5D-method-%5Bfsharp%5D) to execute them in parallel. This function takes an `list<Async>` and returns an `Async<list>`:

```
let allResults = urls |> List.map getAsync |> Async.Parallel
```

Comment: thanks for the attempt, the referenced doc says "initially queueing each as work items", I'm not clear on the throttle part, is it requesting one url at a time, or all 100 in parallel?

Comment: is there a way to control the throttle with Async.Parallel, I'm also looking at Mailbox Processor, and not sure if that's where the solution is, https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/concurrency-actor-model/

Comment: Queueing as work item means that the next available thread from the thread pool will execute the task.
So depend on the size of the thread pool you will have concurrent calls. 

you can see here a good summary of async in .net (F#):
https://medium.com/jettech/f-async-guide-eb3c8a2d180a